# google sheet generated html form not "lining up"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I get dynamic content from multiple google sheets (within one google sheet) into the same html form?

In the code below, I dynamically create the html form from a main sheet. I want to add a form select, from a supplemental sheet. I cannot get the form.select to be part of one html form.

**EDIT:** (1) updated var html to include div's for each row. (2) moved form and table html into the html page directly. Form values are still not lining up correctly. Should I be using HTML Template instead?

```html
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    function setPageValues () {
      //this is working as intended
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayForm).getValuesFromSS(); 
      }
   
    function displayForm (values) {   
      var colsUsed = [4,5,0,13,15,16,17,18];        //sheet cols for form
      var html = "<form><table border=0 width=90%>"; //start the form
     
     //HERE IS THE ISSUE: gets range no problem, but html form is wrong.
     //setting return value "html +=" doesn't work!
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayPick).getValuesForRngName('CategoryRole');
   
     //make the rest of the table (this all works fine)
      for (var j = 0; j < colsUsed.length; j++){
          colUsed = colsUsed[j]
          html += "<div id=row><tr><th align=right>" + values[0][colUsed] + ":*&nbsp;</th>";
          html += "<td><input></input type=text></td></tr></div>";
      }
      
      //close out the table and set the value (this all works fine)
      html += "<tr><td></td><td><input type=submit></td></tr></form></table>";
      html += "<i>* required form data.</i>";
      document.getElementById("forminfo").innerHTML = html;
    }  

  //building the pick list works just fine. results not correct in html
  //tried to "return html;" but this didn't work!
  function displayPick (values) {
    var rows = 10000;
    var catUsed = "34-31 21: Supplier";

    //find limit of column values
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      if (values[i] == '') { 
        var rows = i;
        break;
       } 
    }
    
    //build the select field description, and set selected option
    html = "<div id=row><tr><th align=right>" + values[0] + ":*&nbsp;</th><td><select>";
    for (var i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
      if (values[i] == catUsed) {
        html += "<option selected>" + values[i] + "<option>";
      } else {
        html += "<option>" + values[i] + "<option>";
      }
    }
    html += "</select></td></tr></div>";
    document.getElementById("formpick").innerHTML = html;
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="setPageValues()">
  <form><table border=0 width=90%>
    <div id="formpick"></div>
    <div id="forminfo"></div>
  </table></form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a function in your project that opens up other Spreadsheets with "openById";  Then return the data to your form with google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(functionName);

Comment: I updated the original question to clarify, both "sheets" are in the same "google spreadsheet". One sheet has the actual data, the other has the allowable select list values. The issue is not getting the the data from either sheet, but having the from the selected list values appear in a single html form.